# android application crashes when using a vector

Tags: java, android, xml

My android activity keeps crashing when i click on the button 1, it is supposed to save a 1 on a vector called numregist, and display a "first number" on a textView, I don't know what i am doing wrong, I would appreciate any help, this is the java code:

```
package com.example.holamundo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Mesa1_1 extends MainActivity {
int counter=0;
int[] numregist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mesa11);

    numregist=new int[0];
}

public void CambiarValorBoton1(View view){
    numregist[counter]=1;
     final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
     t.setText("first number");
}
public void CambiarValorBoton2(View view){
    numregist[counter]=2;
     final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
     t.setText("second number");
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void cerrar(View view){
    finish();
}
```

}

This is my XML code up to button 2:(button 1 is named button 2 and button 2 is named button 3, sorry for that)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="CambiarValorBoton1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="CambiarValorBoton2"
                android:text="2" />
```

Comment: post your stacktrace. `activity keeps crashing` means nothing.

Comment: I guess he is getting out of bounds exception as the size of the array is 0

Answer (score 4):

`numregist=new int[0];` should be `numregist=new int[1];`

---

With `numregist=new int[0];` you're declaring an array that can holds 0 elements.

So when trying to access the first element, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` and thus make your app crashed.

That's not what you want. You want to have an array that can hold one element.

Keep in mind that arrays are 0 base indexed in Java. So to access the first element of `numregist`, you will call `numregist[0]`.

This figure may be helpful :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get rid of the

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

method. Then - you are initializing an array of 0 elements here `numregist=new int[0];`, while you should have at least one element - change it to `numregist=new int[1];` and it should work. If not, please paste the output from logcat so we could help more.